# Unity толкнуть в нужное место rigidbody

Tags: c#, unity3d

Надо чтобы объект начал движение до заданных координат. 
Использовал для этого HOTween v2(DOTween), двигал командой

```
transform.DOMove(Vector3 target, 1f);
```

Проблема в том что он просто даёт направление и скорость, и любое препятствие на пути просто отшвыривает, даже если вес большой. Надо как то сделать так, чтобы он получал импульс и нужное направление, но успешно останавливался тяжёлыми препятствиями. Физика чтоб нормально работало. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я давал примерный ответ на вашем прошлом вопросе. 
Используйте для этого структуру `Vector3` или же объект `transform`. Берёте игровой объект и указываете его как точку куда необходимо держать направление, при помощи `rigidbody.AddForce(other.transform.position, ForceMode.Impulce);`.

Или же добавьте эффект пружины. Для этого есть необходимые компоненты в `Add Component -> Physics -> ...`. Например `SpringJoint`.

Более подробно о `SpringJoint`.
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-SpringJoint.html